# What's the lifecycle of a Java HttpSession object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Obviously at some point an object is created and destroyed/returned to pool.  I'm especially interested in how these are garbage-collected.  Is there any way to control this behavior?  Specifically, will a call to `invalidate()` mark these objects for collection?  When do they release any references stored in them?

The more detail the better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) is basically a map from string key to some arbitrary value. Every time you create a session (by accessing JSP or calling `getSession()`/`getSession(true)`), the container will generate unique string session ID and hold a reference to that `HttpSession` object. Again, it will use a map from session ID to `HttpSession` object.

Once you put something in the session, the container holds a reference to that session and the session holds a reference to your object. It will stay there for some time. There are three situation when your item will be removed from the session:

1. When you explicitly remove it (`removeAttribute()` or `setAttribute(null)`)
2. When you `invalidate()` the whole session. This basically removes all attributes and removes the whole session from container-managed session map
3. When the session expires (same behaviour as with 2.) This happens when no servlet/JSP accessed session in configurable amount of time (e.g. 10 minutes)

The moment an object is removed from the session (any of the points above) and no other code holds a reference to that object, it is eligible for garbage collection and will be removed during next GC run.

---

You can add an object that implements *HttpSessionBindingListener* to an *HttpSession* to observe some of the behaviour described above. An object that implements this interface could, for example, print a log message when it is unbound from the session.

You can check out the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on the container you use, the question of implementation.